# Symfony app 403 Forbidden error: You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: php, apache, permissions, symfony

I'm trying to run a symfony app on a CentOS7 linode server, but I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot serve directory <path to project>: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html, index.php)
```

I have a vhost setup for this subdomain with this config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin pak11273@gmail.com
     ServerName mister
     ServerAlias project.mystuff.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project
     ErrorLog /var/www/html/project/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/html/project/logs/access.log combined
     <Directory "/var/www/html/project" >
         #Options FollowSymLinks
         Options -Indexes
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My current settings are:
1) My webserver user and group is apache
2) My permissions to the /var/www/html/project are 755 with apache:apache

I've tried the following suggestions on the internet to no avail:

1) Changed Options -Indexes to Options +Indexes
2) Added DirectoryIndex index.html
3) I get server errors if I change root ownership of /var

Comment: shouldn't you be pointing to app.php and not index.html?

Comment: Did you replace the `web` directory that is shipped with the Symfony Standard Edition to `project` or does the `/var/www/html/project` directory point to your project's root directory?

Comment: @xabbuh is correct - I've updated my post. Try that out.

Comment: Yes, I was missing the web directory.  It is in the web server setup in the symfony docs but I must have missed it.

Comment: @xabbuh Do I mark Bunk's answer as correct? You gave the correct answer to my question in your comment but I don't know if this resolves this question.

Comment: As Alvin's answer now contains all the needed information I am totally fine if you accept his answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using CentOS 6 and Apache. Try this change:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin pak11273@gmail.com
     ServerName mister
     ServerAlias project.mystuff.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/web
     ErrorLog /var/www/html/project/var/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/html/project/var/logs/access.log combined
     <Directory "/var/www/html/project/web" >
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also verify you can use `wget` or `curl` to get your Symfony index.html page on the localhost. CentOS might have enabled SELinux or even iptables.

Use `sestatus` to see if it is set to enforcing - if so you need to allow web or disable SELinux temporarily.

xabbuh is correct. The "web" directory is the folder you need to use as your web root. If updated my post to reflect the changes needed.

Comment: You can also look at [this link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html).

Comment: Hi there Isaac. You can mark mine by select both the up arrow and green check mark. Also take a look at my blog on setting up [Apache & Symfony on RHEL](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/05/11/apache-symfony-on-rhel/), which will be similar to CentOS. I think the blog might help you with other things too.

Comment: for me it was just `AllowOverride All` that was needed but missing

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Apache configuration, it appears you're trying to serve your Symfony project from /var/www/html/project. However, by convention, Symfony applications should be served from the public directory located within the root of your Symfony project. Trying to serve from the root directory could cause issues, such as a 403 error. Could you confirm whether your DocumentRoot is set to the root directory of your Symfony project or the public directory within it? If it's set to the root directory, changing the DocumentRoot to the public directory might solve your problem